# Create a dynamic subclass in Rails that works with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, anonymous-class, sti

I want to combine the two following things:

### My STI structure:

Assume a Rails model `User`. There are only two types of users, namely `Admin` and `Customer`. The STI column is `type`, the table is called `users` but in practice, we will never have and `User` objects around, just `Admins` and `Customers`.

- `User` (used for storing all data and implementing common functionality, but never instanciated)

  - `Admin`
  - `Customer < User`

### Dynamically extend models:

In some cases, it is handy to dynamically extend a model class, to temporarely have an object with more capabilities to carry out a specific action. Assume my `create` controller action checks for an additional field "Send welcome mail" (which is provided by the `new` form). The attribute is virtual, thus we can use it in the form as if it was a normal column. This can be realized with:

```rb
extended_user_class = Class.new(User)
extended_user_class.send(:include, MyAwesomeMixins)
extended_user_class.class_eval do
  my_virtual_attribute :send_welcome_mail, default: true
end

model = extended_user_class.new
# send model to the view and it "just works"
```

### Combining both

Unfortunately combining both of these techniques does not work in the way described above, because Rails STI appears to be broken by anonymous classes:

```
[1] pry(main)> User.where(id: 1).to_sql
=> "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1"
[2] pry(main)> Class.new(User).where(id: 1).to_sql
=> "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 1"
```

EDIT: To reproduce the above, must be in production env.

The second statement is wrong because it filters by type. The first statement is the intended behavior.

So, apearently anonymous classes are bad for STI. Redefining the constant `User` as described in https://dev.to/factorial/a-trick-with-ruby-anonymous-classes-11pp is likely to break the application - I want the extended class to only be used when called explicitely (`extended_user_class`) - `User` has to be unaffected.

Can this be achieved in Ruby 3 / Rails 6?

Comment: It feels to me like the pattern you describe is very similar to the DCI pattern that was popular in the Rails community about 10 years ago. At the time I really disliked this pattern – mostly for the reason that it makes the code harder to understand and to work with because you cannot be sure anymore that an instance of a class behaves in the same way in two different places in your application. You always have to double-check if the instance needs to be changed in some way to work in a specific context.

Comment: But even more important Tthis pattern has [a huge impact on your application's performance](https://tonyarcieri.com/dci-in-ruby-is-completely-broken).

Comment: I don't get the same issue in my "rails console". `Class.new(Client).where(id: 1).to_sql` -> `"SELECT \"clients\".* FROM \"clients\" WHERE \"clients\".\"id\" = 1"`

Comment: that's a hell of a read @spickermann!

Comment: This looks more like a solution looking for a problem. You can use form objects if you want to remove the logic of dealing with a form from a model itself and I can't see why you would want to dynamically generate the subclasses since there is only two of them. Anonymnous classes aren't just bad for STI. ActiveModel and ActiveRecord base a huge number of assumptions on the class name. YAGNI.

Comment: @Jad it only occurs in production environment

Answer (score 0):

Two potential solutions:

**Singleton class**

Experimenting showed that singleton classes (also known as Eigenclasses) would likely provide a solution, however there could be a performance loss of down to 25%.

So the part dynamically extending the model would become:

1. Operate on the normal User class
2. Instantiate a new User
3. Add the virtual attributes to that one instance by using its singleton class

**Patch the anonymous class to pretend that it is the superclass**

In this solution, the anonymous class is extended with a mixin that delegates the following three class methods to `superclass`:

- `finder_needs_type_condition?`
- `descendants`
- `name`

For instance:

```rb
def name
  superclass.name
end
```

This way, the anonymous class becomes transparent and behaves like the class it inherits from. This solution is a rather ugly hack but it appears to work in practice. It is uglier but faster than the singleton class solution.

There is one caveat however:

```rb
User.all == [admin1, admin2, customer1]
admin1.class == Admin
extended_admin1 = extend_using_patch(admin1)
extended_admin1.class.name == "User"
```

As can be seen, the anonymous class `extended_admin1` extends `User`, not `Admin`.